# Change data capture (CDC) is not supported.

Tags: sql-server-2008, cdc

Does anyone know which versions on SQL Server supports CDC? On my machine:
Microsoft SQL Server Developer (64-bit)
Microsoft Windows NT 6.1 (7601)
NT x64
11.0.5058.0

I got an error that "Change data capture is not supported on system databases, or on a distribution database. "

Comment: Here is a link for getting started with CDC http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/getting-starting-with-change-data-capture-cdc-in-sql-server-part-2.html and gives the system proc to enable(available in 2008, 2008 R2, 2012 and 2014)

Comment: Read the message again - it's not telling you that CDC is unavailable, it's telling you that it can't be used *in the specific database you're trying to enable it in*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqlserver 2008 have introduced this feature.

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1474/using-change-data-capture-cdc-in-sql-server-2008/

You can enable/disable this feature.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627369.aspx

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510486%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

For your error , its need sqlserver job feature. 
"Use the stored procedure ‘sys.sp_cdc_add_job’ to add the Change Data Capture job."

http://www.sqlserverf1.com/tag/could-not-enable-change-data-capture-for-database-s-change-data-capture-is-not-supported-on-system-databases/

http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=169473

Comment: Thank You Ajay2707. That day You have saved my life. I woudn't figure out that " sp_changedbowner 'sa' " statement will solve all issue with enabling CDC.